Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Boost"
today i decided to make a basic web server that listens http requests with Boost.asio
Server.cpp Code:
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

void session(tcp::socket socket) {
    try {
        for (;;) {
            char data[1024];

            boost::system::error_code error;
            size_t length = socket.read_some(boost::asio::buffer(data), error);

            if (error == boost::asio::error::eof)
                break; // Connection closed cleanly by peer.
            else if (error)
                throw boost::system::system_error(error); // Some other error.

            boost::asio::write(socket, boost::asio::buffer(data, length));
        }
    } catch (std::exception& e) {
        std::cerr << "Exception in thread: " << e.what() << "\n";
    }
}

void server(boost::asio::io_context& io_context, short port) {
    tcp::acceptor acceptor(io_context, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), port));
    for (;;) {
        tcp::socket socket(io_context);
        acceptor.accept(socket);
        std::thread(session, std::move(socket)).detach();
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    try {
        if (argc != 2) {
            std::cerr << "Usage: server <port>\n";
            return 1;
        }

        boost::asio::io_context io_context;

        server(io_context, std::atoi(argv[1]));
    } catch (std::exception& e) {
        std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}

CMakeLists.txt :
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(WebServer)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

find_package(Boost 1.70 REQUIRED COMPONENTS system)
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(WebServer server.cpp)
target_link_libraries(WebServer ${Boost_LIBRARIES})

When I compiled the project I get the error :
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindBoost.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "Boost", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Boost" (requested
  version 1.70) with any of the following names:

    BoostConfig.cmake
    boost-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Boost" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "Boost_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "Boost"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.

When i compiled normally, servers crashes when some requestes come
Runtime Error :
Exception in thread: read_some: End of file
Exception in thread: Bad file descriptor
Exception in thread: Invalid argument

What i did:

Installed Boost lib
I runned Cmake building commands
Tried to run the server
I get error I tried other versions of Boost and Reconfigured the Cmake file but error continues
I think i have problem with boost or cmake


How did you install boost? There is more than one way. Where did you install boost?

To use boost with cmake I recommend that you use a package manager (whichever one is appropriate for your platform). That should sort out the cmake boost connection.

using apt libboost-all-dev

That doesnt solves the problem but thanks!

OK, try find_package(Boost 1.70 REQUIRED COMPONENTS system CONFIG). I would expect that to work.

CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:11 (find_package):
Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Boost" (requested
version 1.70) with any of the following names:
BoostConfig.cmake
boost-config.cmake

Add the installation prefix of "Boost" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
"Boost_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "Boost"
provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
installed.

Not sure if I understand it: first you got a CMake error, telling you that boost cannot be found, and then you somehow managed to run your program? How, if it cannot even be compiled?

OK I'm out of ideas, CONFIG works for me but I don't use apt. Probably you should look in your installation for one of the files that cmake is looking for (with or without CONFIG) and if you find one then you need to point cmake at the file somehow.

Oh sorry its my bad english ill fix

I'm searching some mentioned files with commands they exist but still get error?????

If you want to focus your question on the problem with find_package(Boost 1.70, remove unrelated c++ code, and paste the output of cmake -DCMAKE_FIND_DEBUG_MODE=ON ../ . It will show you the paths it tried to look for Boost cmake file.

/usr/include/boost , apt installs that path too

@Lilla I guess you need to set Boost_DIR to whichever directory contains those files.

i setted, not matters lol
